# A [non-destructive] better (not really) `strtok` function

Tags: c, strings, memory-management

The first time I used `strtok`, it felt, well, weird. But after a while, I became quite used to it. In a way it was simple. Soon after reading a bunch of Stack Overflow comments and posts about this function, I came to realize that this isn't what I *should* use in the long run.

Personally, my biggest problem with `strtok` was that it was a destructive function. So today I just wanted to make a version of it that **non-destructive**.

So the way this new version is going to be used, is just the same as `strtok`.

```
token = get_token
while token is valid
    (do something with the token)
    token = get_token
```

The only change I made (to make my job somewhat easier) is instead of a `char *` delimiter, I'm taking an `int`. So the function signature is now

```c
char *tokenize(const char *__src, int delim);
```

Before looking at the source code, let me show you how much identical this function is in regard to the `strtok` function using a snippet.

```c
char string[] =
      "The exec() functions return only if an error has occurred. The return "
      "value is - 1, and errno is set to indicate the error.";
char *token = tokenize(string, ' ');
while (token)
  {
    printf("'%s'\n", token);
    token = tokenize(NULL, ' ');
  }
```

*This solution is made from an educational perspective, nothing more. I'm not claiming this to be a viable alternative to `strtok`.*

---

##### To briefly explain how I've written this function

The function returns a `malloc`'d `char *` that contains the token. Instead of allocating just the amount of memory required to store the substring, it allocates 8 more bytes to store the index address from the source `char *` that will be used in the next iteration to look for the next token.

It also frees the previous `malloc`'d block upon each iteration. Yes, if you don't go through the whole string, you'll have a memory leak (or you'll have to add a weird call to `free` yourself with the correct address, `- sizeof(char *)` being the offset).

I'm using `assert` to handle the errors, as it's faster and simple enough for this situation, and most importantly gets the job done.

---

##### The source

```c
char *tokenize(const char *__src, int delim)
{
  static const char *src;
  static char *token;
  const char *start_pos_loc;

  if (__src)
    {
      src = __src;
    }

  if (!token)
    {
      start_pos_loc = src;
    }
  else
    {
      memcpy(&start_pos_loc, token - sizeof(char *), sizeof(char *));
      free((void *)token - sizeof(char *));
    }

  size_t substring_length = 0;
  const char *ptr;

  for (ptr = start_pos_loc; *ptr != 0 && *ptr != delim; ptr++)
    {
      substring_length++;
    }

  if (!substring_length)
    {
      return NULL;
    }

  // Skipping the final delimiter.
  ptr++;

  token = malloc(substring_length + 1 + sizeof(char *));
  assert(token);

  memcpy(token, &ptr, sizeof(char *));
  token += sizeof(char *);
  memcpy(token, start_pos_loc, substring_length);

  token[substring_length] = 0;

  return token;
}
```

One of the things that I'm mostly looking forward to, is knowing if I'm using `const` correctly or not.

Apart from that, take the following `main` function for example:-

```c
int main()
{
  char string[] = "Hello World! How is life now?";
  char *token = tokenize(string, ' ');
  while (token)
    {
      printf("'%s'\n", token);
      token = tokenize(NULL, ' ');
    }
  return 0;
}
```

After running it under valgrind, I'm getting this error:-

```
==42519== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==42519==    at 0x109287: tokenize (in /home/debdut/Documents/cpp/a.out)
==42519==    by 0x1093F9: main (in /home/debdut/Documents/cpp/a.out)
```

Any idea where might this be coming from?

Thank you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too complicated.

No wonder you try to simplify by using debugging-constructs for release error-detection.

1. Don't try to shoehorn a third variable somewhere into the dynamic allocation. The awkwardness is unneeded. Especially as you only need two static pointers: the returned token, and the resume position.
2. You have the choice: `free()`+`malloc()` or `realloc()`/`free()`. The former potentially wastes time.

```
char* tokenize(const char* restrict s, int c) {
    static const char *p
    static char *r;
    s = p = s ? s : p;
    assert(s);
    if (!*s) {
        free(r);
        r = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    while (*p && *p != c)
        ++p;
    r = realloc(r, p - s + 1);
    if (!r) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for a token.\n");
        abort();
    }
    memcpy(r, s, p - s);
    r[p - s] = 0;
    if (*p) ++p;
    return r;
}
```

That was done under the assumption that you really want `tokenize()` to manage the token. There are other arguably better designs:

1. Simply handing it off to the caller and letting him free it when its time. Probably not significantly less efficient, often better as a copy is needed anyway.
2. Simply return start- and end-pointer, and let the caller do whatever he wants. Simpler and more flexible, though often more cumbersome to use.

Possible alternative reentrant design:

```
typedef struct tokenize_context {
    const char *input;
    char *token;
} tokenize_context;

char* tokenize(tokenize_context* restrict p, int c) {
    assert(p && p->input);
    if (!*p->input) {
        free(p->token);
        p->token = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    const char* const begin = p->input;
    while (*p->input && *p->input != c)
        ++p->input;
    p->token = realloc(p->token, p->input - begin + 1);
    if (!p->token) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for a token.\n");
        abort();
    }
    memcpy(p->token, begin, p->input - begin);
    p->token[p->input - begin] = 0;
    if (*p->input) ++p->input;
    return p->token;
}
```

Used like:

```
tokenize_context ctx{"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."};
while (tokenize(&ctx, ' ')) {
    // Use ctx.token, or return-value from the above call
    // May steel ctx.token by setting to 0
    // May free ctx.token for early stop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   token = malloc(substring_length + 1 + sizeof(char *));
>   assert(token);
> ```

This `assert()` is wrong.  You're claiming that `malloc()` can't return a null pointer - but it can, and does.

You'll need to examine `token` and return a failure indicator if it's null, before the `assert()`.